# "isUseingPreset" is not accessed Pylance

Tags: python, variables, pylance

I have a global var, and when i use it in a function it says "isUseingPreset is not accessed Pylance".

here is the code :

```py
isUseingPreset = False


def PresetHELLO():
    print("preset HELLO")
    env.PAYLOAD["content"] = "Hello"
    isUseingPreset = True
    reveiewInput()
```

[image: photo of the error]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Comment: YES THANK YOU, i was stuck on this for awhile